# Split a text file into smaller files

Tags: c#

I have a 1000 000 record text file, so I want to split the file into many files which will have 100 records each. Here is my code which I used listbox1 to control the file. The code is working, but with fewer records missing.

```
private void WriteToFile()
    {
        int RowCount = listBox1.Items.Count;
        string FileName = "C:\\Users\\bbdnet0986\\Documents\\MyExpotedQADATA";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName + ".txt");
        int inc = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName+inc + ".txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
             sw.WriteLine(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
             string me = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();

             if (RowCount > 100)
             {

                 listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[counter].ToString());
                 counter++;
                 if (counter == 100)
                 {

                     inc++;
                     sw = new StreamWriter(FileName + inc + ".txt");


                     RowCount = RowCount - counter;
                     counter = 0;

                 }
             }

             else
             {
                  sw.WriteLine(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
             }

         }
         sw.Close();
    }
```

Comment: A ListBox is not well suited or intended to hold 1M items.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
sw = new StreamWriter(FileName + inc + ".txt");
```

You need to .Flush() the previous sw. The writer is buffered, thats why some records are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your question is related to your `ListBox`, so i'll show you a solution which creates files from a huge file every 100th line.

It's easy with `Linq` and [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx):

```
int maxLineCount = 100;
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(hugeFilePath);

var fileGroups = File.ReadLines(file.FullName)
    .Select((l, i) => new { Line = l, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / maxLineCount)
    .Select(grp => new { FileIndex = grp.Key, Lines = grp.Select(x => x.Line)});

foreach (var grp in fileGroups)
{
    var fileName = "File" + grp.FileIndex;
    var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\Test", fileName + file.Extension).ToString();
    File.WriteAllLines(path, grp.Lines);
}
```

Note that `File.ReadLines` streams the lines instead of loading all into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much easier way:

```
private void WriteToFile() 
{ 
    // get an array of strings - you'll find out way :)
    string[] items = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray();

    // this would also work with ReadAllLines()
    string[] items = File.ReadAllLines("Your original file");

    // path + filename prefix
    string fileNamePattern = "C:\\Users\\bbdnet0986\\Documents\\MyExpotedQADATA{0}.txt"; 

    // blocks of 100
    string[] buffer;
    for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i += 100)
    {
        // slice the string array into 100 string blocks
        buffer = items.Slice(i, 100);

        // output the block of strings
        File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(fileNamePattern, i), buffer);
    }
}
```

Slice Extension:

```
    public static T[] Slice<T>(this T[] source, int index, int length)
    {
        T[] slice = new T[length];
        Array.Copy(source, index, slice, 0, length);
        return slice;
    }
```

Comment: This unnecessarily  loads 1000000 lines into memory at once.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - An alternate approach since you already took the best answer.  Also note that my solution is faster than LINQ and .NET 2.0-3.5 (VS 2008) friendly :)  However, I suppose I could have used a FileStream instead.